# Facebook Share not showing image with valid og:image metatag (php)

Tags: php, reactjs, facebook-sharer, facebook-share

We have a share button (our own button) for our clients. For a page such as:

```
https://www.wyomingforsale.net/idx/listing/WY-CCBOR/22-658/3-Pine-Cone-Ln-Moorcroft-WY-82721
```

We get to this page:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wyomingforsale.net%2Fidx%2Flisting%2FWY-CCBOR%2F22-658%2F3-Pine-Cone-Ln-Moorcroft-WY-82721&
```

The problem is that the image is blank. There is a valid og:image tag on the page. I have used the sharing debugger with the same results - the preview shows an empty image. The canonical URL looks correct and identical to the fetched URL. Looking in the debugger at the value for og:image, that URL looks good, and if I plug that into my browser, the image shows up. What am I missing?  This is a React-drawn page, if that makes any difference.

Comment: did you try with a lower resolution? I'm guessing 3000px is to much

Comment: When I try to open your `og:image` i get `Access Denied` error

Comment: Thanks!

Hmm.. Konrad, I'm not getting that error - I have tried different browsers, incognito windows, even a different computer. I'll check more into that.

DarkBee - didn't think of that, I'll see about using a lower resolution image

Comment: Well, per the FB docs, there doesn't seem to be a max resolution limit, though there is a minimum limit. The only max is file size, 8MB, but this image is definitely less than that (786.6KB)  Weirdly, looking at the image in the sharing debugger has no errors, but a blank (black) image preview.

Comment: OK, FYI: I tried a different, smaller image in the Facebook Sharing Debugger, and still get an empty image:     https://storage.googleapis.com/idx-photos-gs.ihouseprd.com/WY-CCBOR/06-1586/2x/000.jpg